# Load website in iframe dialog, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the following example to display a website in an iframe on my website. I use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a#verd').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var horizontalPadding = 30;
    var verticalPadding = 30;
    $('<iframe id="externalSite" class="externalSite" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
        title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'External Site',
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        autoResize: true,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: "black"
        }
    }).width(800 - horizontalPadding).height(500 - verticalPadding);            
});
....
});
```

....it is exactly the same code as in the example but it does not work for me. however the click event is triggerd, I tested it with alert. Any ideas whats wrong?

EDIT:

my site structure

```
<html><head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/frontend.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.corner.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#beginning').click(function() { $.post('/programme/list/page/1', {"format":"json"}, function(data, textStatus) { displayProgramms(data); }, 'html');return false; });
    $('a#end').click(function() { $.post('/programme/list/page/11', {"format":"json"}, function(data, textStatus) { displayProgramms(data); }, 'html');return false; });
});
//-->

</script></head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
</div>
</div>
<div id="navholder">
...
</div>
<div id="contentwrapper" class="frontpage">
....
</div>
<div id="sidewrapper">
...
</div>
<div id="footerwrapper">
...
</div>
<div id="disclaimer">
...
</div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

the js code is located in frontend.js

Comment: could you show the html?

Comment: facing another problem. I include the ui js but it is not displayed in the header. I use zend framework, posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738105/set-jqueryuipath-in-zend-framework-project

Comment: solved it now and it works. thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works fine for me. Make sure you  have a link with and id of "verd" in your html also make sure you have [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/) loaded ?

**EDIT**

from your html looks like your missing [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: what to you mean with ui? oO have not any jquery ui loaded

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
in the head of your html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('a#verd').click(function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    var self = $(this),
        horizontalPadding = 30,
        verticalPadding = 30,
        dtitle = $(this).attr('title')) ? $(this).attr('title') : 'External Site';

    $('<iframe id="externalSite" class="externalSite" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog(
      {
        title: dtitle,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        autoResize: true,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: "black"
        }
      }
    ).width(800 - horizontalPadding).height(500 - verticalPadding);            

    return false;   
});
```

???
are you calling jquery ui?